# Defocus application when last window closes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Not sure if this is the right word to use but i need to "Defocus" my application when the user closes the last window (Order it to the background). Preferably giving the focus to the application that was running in the foreground before my application became foreground. How do I go about achieving this?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`-[NSApplication deactivate]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/deactivate).

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] deactivate];
```

If that doesn't do what you want (which is entirely likely), try this:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:nil];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] unhideWithoutActivation];
```

Note that this is not necessarily something that you should be doing. If I'm picturing what your application is doing correctly, it seems that you should consider making it an [agent application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SoftwareDevelopment/SoftwareDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH206-TPXREF111).

Comment: Thanks John! the second one did the trick! Thank you for the tip on the "agent application". I will have a look at it.